# Integrating Metronic with Laravel 8 - Webmix Failing

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I am in the process of integrating Metronic 8 with Laravel 8.

I have followed the guide from Metronic in their documentation but when I run `npm run dev` it webmix gets to 98% and then fails with the following output:

```
ERROR in ./resources/src/sass/style.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
6 │ @import "../../../../tools/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  resources/src/sass/components/components.scss 6:9  @import
  resources/src/sass/style.scss 12:9                 root stylesheet
    at processResult (/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:721:19)
    at /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:827:5
    at /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7
    at Function.call$2 (/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:95825:16)
    at _render_closure1.call$2 (/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:83882:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:28060:18)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26590:21)

ERROR in /assets/js/scripts.bundle
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/saas/resources/src/webpack/scripts.js' in '/Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/s
```

My webpack.mix.js file looks exactly like the example on the documentation:

https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/demo1/documentation/getting-started/integration/laravel.html

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

In the docs where Metronic tells you to swap `../../../../tools` for `~`, i just had to ignore that and just leave it at the root. e.g 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root'